# Add the previous column value with the current value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to figure out the logic to write the python code for below requirement. Basically what I want the expected output is, if **IDLE != 0**, 'Duration' value should be above cell value + idle. I will be getting a live data with data resolution of 5 minutes. I want to send the *duration* to a collection. How can I create a logic for this?

Consider below logic (not syntax) I came up until now:

```
if (df["SPEED"].mean()) != 0:
    df["DURATION"] = 0
    for i in range (len(df)):
        if (df.loc[i, "IDLE"]) == 0:
            df["DURATION"] = df["DISTANCE"]/df["SPEED"]

for i in range (len(df)):
    if (df.loc[i, "DURATION"]) == 0:
        (df.loc[i, "DURATION"]) = ((df.loc[i-1, "DURATION"])+(df.loc[i, "IDLE"]))
.
.
```

The above code I written is not working.
if wondering why **if mean(speed)!=0**? so that initially when speed = 0, I don't want to send output
How should I proceed next?

```
   DISTANCE  SPEED  IDLE  DURATION  EXPECTED_OUTPUT
0         X    0.0     5         0                0
1         X    0.0     5         0                0
2         X    0.2     0        10               10
3         X    0.2     0        10               10
4         X    0.2     0        10               10
5         X    0.2     0        10               10
6         X    0.0     5         0               15
7         X    0.0     5         0               20
8         X    0.2     0        10               10
9         X    0.2     0        10               10
10        X    0.2     0        10               10
11        X    0.2     0        10               10
```

Comment: Please, do not share data as a picture but in `text` format in order readers can easily *copy/past* it.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: From you current dataframe, just print it and copy past the console output. Then, edit the question and replace the picture with the pasted dataframe.

Comment: DISTANCE SPEED IDLE DURATION EXPECTED_OUTPUT
0 X 0.0 5 0 0
1 X 0.0 5 0 0
2 X 0.2 0 10 10
3 X 0.2 0 10 10
4 X 0.2 0 10 10
5 X 0.2 0 10 10
6 X 0.0 5 0 15
7 X 0.0 5 0 20
8 X 0.2 0 10 10
9 X 0.2 0 10 10
10 X 0.2 0 10 10
11 X 0.2 0 10 10

Comment: Please, share it in the question, not in comment, thank's!

Comment: should i paste the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution might be to iterate over the dataframe.

1. Find the index of the first `speed` other than 0. There are a lot of ways to do that, you can try the following:

```
df[df["SPEED"] != 0].index[0]
```

2. Copy the `Duration` column in the `EXPECTED_OUTPUT` column:

```
df["EXPECTED_OUTPUT"] = df["DURATION"]
```

3. Iterate over the `dataframe` rows starting at the index find in step 1.(here I make the assumption that index rows are sorted).

   1. Check if the `duration` is 0:
   2. If 1 is verified, verified a previous row exists:

      -> YES: add the previous `EXPECTED_OUTPUT` cell to current `IDLE`

      -> NO : set the value you want (here NaN). Set nothing to let the `DURATION` value

---

**Full code**:

```
# Find index where speed starting being != 0
index = df[df["SPEED"] != 0].index[0]
print(index)
# 2

# Copy duration column in expected output
df["EXPECTED_OUTPUT"] = df["DURATION"]

# Iterate over duration row
for i in range(index, len(df)):
    # If duration == 0
    if df.loc[i, 'DURATION'] == 0:
        # Check a previous row exist
        if i > 0:
            df.loc[i, 'EXPECTED_OUTPUT'] = df.loc[i, "IDLE"] + df.loc[i - 1, "EXPECTED_OUTPUT"]
        # If previous row doesn't exist : set NaN
        # You can remove this else statement to have the "duration" value
        # Depends on you
        else:
            df.loc[i, 'EXPECTED_OUTPUT'] = np.NaN

print(df)
#    DISTANCE  SPEED  IDLE  DURATION  EXPECTED_OUTPUT
# 0         X    0.0     5         0                0
# 1         X    0.0     5         0                0
# 2         X    0.2     0        10               10
# 3         X    0.2     0        10               10
# 4         X    0.2     0        10               10
# 5         X    0.2     0        10               10
# 6         X    0.0     5         0               15
# 7         X    0.0     5         0               20
# 8         X    0.2     0        10               10
# 9         X    0.2     0        10               10
# 10        X    0.2     0        10               10
# 11        X    0.2     0        10               10
```

Comment: what if initially i have only 2 rows, and speed is still 0, is the condition I've written good enough or is there a better way?

Comment: About the python code or the approach you suggested ?

Comment: about my approach

Comment: This lacks of context, so in short I don't know. If you want some review for your work, you could share the code on [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) by explaining your work, context, constraint, etc.

Answer (score 1):

i worked out a solution

```
for i in range (1,len(df)):
    if (df.loc[i, "DURATION"]) == 0:
        (df.loc[i, "DURATION"]) = ((df.loc[i-1, "DURATION"])+(df.loc[i, "IDLE"]))
```